# esp8266 ошибка при работе любой прошивки

Tags: esp8266

суть проблемы: при прошивке esp8266 тем-же blink ну или любой другой прошивкой  она нормально работает 1-2 минуты а иногда и меньше потом перезагружается и начинает выгружать в порт вот это:

```
>>>stack>>>

ctx: sys
sp: 3fffeaa0 end: 3fffffb0 offset: 01a0
3fffec40:  00000001 402011f5 00000001 3ffee2e0  
3fffec50:  402018a8 ffffffff ffffffff 40104443  
3fffec60:  40104424 3fffc100 00000002 00000009  
3fffec70:  00000000 4021f52d ffffffff ffffffff  
3fffec80:  400005e1 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
3fffec90:  4021f52d 00000030 00000010 ffffffff  
3fffeca0:  ff03116e 3ffeac0e 3ffeac34 00000001  
3fffecb0:  000fac02 3ffeac34 00000000 3ffeaccf  
3fffecc0:  00000008 00000082 0000008c 3ffef024  
3fffecd0:  3fffee80 00000002 00000002 00000009  
3fffece0:  ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
3fffecf0:  ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
3fffed00:  ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
3fffed10:  ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
3fffed20:  ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
3fffed30:  ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
3fffed40:  ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
3fffed50:  ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
3fffed60:  402230b3 ffffffff ffffffff 40239570  
3fffed70:  402235e5 3ffef024 3fffee80 00000000  
3fffed80:  00000000 00000001 00000016 401001f0  
3fffed90:  3ffeac3a 3ffeac34 ff03116e 4021b884  
3fffeda0:  00000001 0000000a 00000002 00000002  
3fffedb0:  00000005 00000000 00000020 40100d06  
3fffedc0:  00000002 00000008 00000008 00000002  
3fffedd0:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
3fffede0:  ffffffaa 3ffeabdc 4021bb39 3fffee80  
3fffedf0:  3ffed4d0 3ffece68 3ffeabdc 00000001  
3fffee00:  00000014 0075d94f 40102036 00000100  
3fffee10:  7fffffff 3ffe92a0 3ffe92a0 00000001  
3fffee20:  40217fc9 00000050 40100e4f 3ffef024  
3fffee30:  3ffeac00 3ffeabe6 ffffffaa 00000002  
3fffee40:  3ffec480 0000000a 00000001 4021c98b  
3fffee50:  00000001 3ffeea2c 3ffeabdc 00000000  
3fffee60:  3ffeabdc 00000000 0000001e ffffffff  
3fffee70:  40000f58 00000000 00000020 00000000  
3fffee80:  00000000 04310303 00640100 00000000  
3fffee90:  3ffeac00 0000016c 00000000 3ffeabf4  
3fffeea0:  00000000 3ffeac00 3ffeac0e 3ffeac34  
3fffeeb0:  00000000 00000000 3ffeac1e 3ffeac6e  
3fffeec0:  3ffeac3a 3ffeac56 00000000 3ffeaccf  
3fffeed0:  00000000 00000000 0000000a 00000000  
3fffeee0:  3ffeedf4 4021c3fe 3ffec480 3ffeea2c  
3fffeef0:  00000000 00000000 3ffec480 3ffeabdc  
3fffef00:  00000000 00000194 00000000 0000000a  
3fffef10:  00000000 3ffeabe6 40225d07 3ffec480  
3fffef20:  3ffeabd0 3fffdcc0 3ffe8a30 3ffe8a30  
3fffef30:  00000050 3ffec480 00000002 00000000  
3fffef40:  402255c7 3fffdab0 00000000 00000004  
3fffef50:  3ffe8a30 40000f49 3fffdab0 40000f49  
3fffef60:  40000e19 40001878 00000004 3fffffb0  
3fffef70:  3fffff10 aa55aa55 000000c2 4010420c  
3fffef80:  40104212 00000004 3fffffb0 99a0190c  
3fffef90:  4010000d 1142f000 70414140 2210052f  
3fffefa0:  4010049c 3fffef3c 40100449 3ffffef8  
3fffefb0:  3fffffc0 00000000 00000000 feefeffe  
3fffefc0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3fffefd0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3fffefe0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3fffeff0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff000:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff010:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff020:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff030:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff040:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff050:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff060:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff070:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff080:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff090:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff100:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff110:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff120:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff130:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff140:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff150:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff160:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff170:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff180:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff190:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff200:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff210:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff220:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff230:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff240:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff250:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff260:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff270:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff280:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff290:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff2f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff300:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff310:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff320:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff330:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff340:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff350:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff360:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff370:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff380:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff390:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff3f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff400:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff410:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff420:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff430:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff440:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff450:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff460:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff470:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff480:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff490:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff4f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff500:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff510:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff520:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff530:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff540:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff550:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff560:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff570:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff580:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff590:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff5f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff600:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff610:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff620:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff630:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff640:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff650:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff660:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff670:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff680:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff690:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff6f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff700:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff710:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff720:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff730:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff740:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff750:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff760:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff770:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff780:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff790:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff7f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff800:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff810:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff820:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff830:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff840:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff850:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff860:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff870:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff880:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff890:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff8f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff900:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff910:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff920:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff930:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff940:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff950:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff960:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff970:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff980:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff990:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff9f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa00:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa10:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa20:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa30:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa40:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa50:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa60:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa70:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa80:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffa90:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffaa0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffab0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffac0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffad0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffae0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffaf0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb00:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb10:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb20:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb30:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb40:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb50:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb60:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb70:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb80:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffb90:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffba0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffbb0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffbc0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffbd0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffbe0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffbf0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc00:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc10:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc20:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc30:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc40:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc50:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc60:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc70:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc80:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffc90:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffca0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffcb0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffcc0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffcd0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffce0:  00000000 00000000 0000001f 401049e5  
3ffffcf0:  4000050c feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffd00:  400043e6 00000030 00000016 ffffffff  
3ffffd10:  400044ab 3fffc718 3ffffe00 08000000  
3ffffd20:  60000200 08000000 08000000 00000000  
3ffffd30:  0000ffff 00042035 00002035 003fd000  
3ffffd40:  4023a7f0 0000049c 003fd000 00000030  
3ffffd50:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffd60:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffd70:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffd80:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffffd90:  feefeffe feefeffe 40226723 00000001  
3ffffda0:  ffffffff 00000000 3ffe8b41 00000008  
3ffffdb0:  40226772 3ffeefcc 3ffeefcc 00000000  
3ffffdc0:  fffffffe 00000000 40100e4f 3ffeefcc  
3ffffdd0:  00000000 00000000 00000020 40100d06  
3ffffde0:  3ffe89f0 4022582f 3ffeefcc 3ffeecd4  
3ffffdf0:  00000000 40219657 3ffecdcc 616e000a  
3ffffe00:  3ffe8624 3fffc6fc 00000001 00000003  
3ffffe10:  3ffef05e 3ffeea2c 00000000 00000000  
3ffffe20:  3ffe8624 3ffe8624 3ffeee27 4021b457  
3ffffe30:  3ffed4d0 4021b050 402013f8 3ffed4d0  
3ffffe40:  40104b28 00245fdc 3ffed600 00000000  
3ffffe50:  3ffedcb0 3ffed600 3ffffe60 3ffee3d8 <
3ffffe60:  00000000 0023cd60 4021d047 3ffed5c8  
3ffffe70:  3ffed600 402013f8 3ffed4d0 aa55aa55  
3ffffe80:  3ffece50 4021cfbc 3ffecdcc 00000002  
3ffffe90:  4021b040 4021b014 3ffece50 00000002  
3ffffea0:  4021afdf 3ffecdcc 00000002 40201734  
3ffffeb0:  4021b590 3ffecdcc 3ffecf48 402013f8  
3ffffec0:  4021afbd 3ffecf48 00000003 3ffecf48  
3ffffed0:  4021d3d5 3fffff20 0000010f 3ffecf48  
3ffffee0:  3ffee298 0000010f 3fffff70 4020b396  
3ffffef0:  402013f8 4022ed4d 3ffe8508 00000000  
3fffff00:  00000000 3ffee298 40201f74 3fffefa0  
3fffff10:  3fffff20 402013f8 00000000 4020158f  
3fffff20:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
3fffff30:  00000000 00000000 3ffe8508 402019c1  
3fffff40:  00000000 00000007 3ffee2e0 40201a4c  
3fffff50:  402024e2 00001388 3ffee2e0 3ffee348  
3fffff60:  3ffee298 00000000 3ffee2e0 402010c2  
3fffff70:  00000000 00000000 fffe0074 40201a4c  
3fffff80:  00000007 00000064 3ffee2e0 40201a70  
3fffff90:  00000000 00000000 00000001 3ffee348  
3fffffa0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffee318 40202024  
<<<stack<<<

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,6)

wdt reset
load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v8b899c12
~ld
Setup done
scan cpart

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,6)

wdt reset
load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v8b899c12
~ld
Setup done
scan start

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,6)

wdt reset
load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v8b899c12
```

несколько раз выдает и начинает работать с начала.
И так постоянно.

какая может быть причина и как это можно исправить?

Версия arduino: 1.8.9

Версия esp8266: 2.5.2

Answer (score 2):

кажется я разобралась в чем проблема была: он вылитает в это  только в энергопотребных операциях например при сканировение wifi

```
    scan start

Exception (9):
epc1=0x40225b2a epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x401006c6 depc=0x00000000

>>>stack>>>

ctx: sys
sp: 3fffed90 end: 3fffffb0 offset: 01a0
3fffef30:  401006a2 4022547e 3fffdab0 00000000  
3fffef40:  3fffdcc0 3ffe8a30 00000000 00000000  
3fffef50:  3ffe8a30 40000f49 3fffdab0 40000f49  
3fffef60:  40000e19 40001878 00000002 00000000  
3fffef70:  3fffff10 aa55aa55 000000c2 4010420c  
3fffef80:  40104212 00000002 00000000 99a0190c  
3fffef90:  4010000d 1142f000 70414140 2210052f  
3fffefa0:  4010049c 3fffef3c 40100449 3ffffef8  
3fffefb0:  3fffffc0 00000000 00000000 feefeffe
```

завтра усилю питание, отпишусь